# I need help finding and downloading traffic data

Tags: data.gov

can anyone direct me to instructions to show how to download traffic data across the US?  I've been all over the site and not finding the data.

Answer (score 1):

**[U.S. Traffic Volume Data](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/tables/tmasdata/)**

State highway agencies collect traffic volume data through both temporary traffic counting and continuous traffic counting programs and report their continuous counting data to FHWA on a monthly basis. Data listed here are reported by states following data format prescribed in FHWA's 2001 Traffic Monitoring Guide located at https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/tmguide/.

You can directly download files from [here](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/tables/tmasdata/), for the below years.

```
Lists by Year: 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
```